# Multiprocessing with Numba

Tags: python, multiprocessing, numba

I'm trying to implement multi cores while using `Numba's` decorator `@njit` I've seen the examples in the multiprocessing documentation, but I'm quite unsure how to introduce it into my script

Here is an example of my code

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, objmode
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import click

core_count = mp.cpu_count()
print(core_count)


def main():
    pass

### hole point of this function is to do mathematical computations
@njit
def multi_core(*args):
    
    pool = mp.Pool()
    b = args[0]
    number = args[1]
    float = args[2]
    a = print(b,number,float)
    pool.close()

    pool.join()
    return a
@click.option('--a','-a', type= int)
@click.option('--b','-b', type= str)
@click.option('--c','-c', type= float)
def test(a,b,c):
    a_num = a
    file_name = b
    float_num = c
    tuple_args = (a_num,file_name,float_num)
    print(multi_core(*tuple_args))
print(test(1,'test.txt',.6))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the multiprocessing example, they call `Process` or `Pool` after `if __name__ == '__main__':`

for example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Since `test()` can hold arbitrary arguments, I'm not sure how to follow the multiprocessing example. This is why I have set up `pool = mp.Pool()` in the `njit` function, but for obvious reason this will not work

Does anyone know how to call `mp.Process()` or `mp.Pool()` with arbitrary arguments

I've tried `mp.Process(target=multi_core, args = (*args))` but that doesn't work.

Also, I've tried to turn `Parallel = True` with `njit`, but there is no speedup. I'm thinking if I were to force multi_core then I'm able to experience a faster run time.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to just run `Process(target=f, args=args)`.

Comment: What is the actual computation you want to make faster? Using `njit(parallel=True)` won't make any arbitrary code faster, only certain supported operations and `for` loops using numbas parallel `prange`. Your test-case doesn't seem very useful since all it does is print a tuple, which can't be parallelized in any way.

Comment: You should not use the multiprocessing package in a Numba code. This will simply not work (Numba will use a fallback implementation which is the basic Python one). What about [reading the documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/parallel.html) in the first place?

Comment: You are not using multiprocessing in your code. You just create and destroy a pool. `main` just `pass`es. Can you provide a reasonable minimum working example? I think I grasp what you are trying to do, but the code does not help. Remove everything that is not necessary to make your question.